# Await promise setTimout is working wrong?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

The `main` function suppose to end after 6s but when running it only took 4s

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("promise1");
    resolve("promise1");
  }, 4000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("promise2");
    resolve("promise2");
  }, 2000);
});

async function main() {
  const result1 = await promise1;
  const result2 = await promise2;
  console.log("end");
}

main();
```

When i look at the terminal i notice that the output `promise2` then `promise1`. Does the code supposed to run promise 1 then promise 2?

Can you guy help explain why and is there any way to **await** for the Promise in this scenario?

Comment: They both start at the same time. Start the second timeout after the first promise resolves

Comment: @jabaa how can they both start since the await keyword should prevent the promise2 from executing until the promise1 is resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you pass to `new Promise` is called **immediately**. It is **not** triggered by `await`.

The `await` keyword just suspends the `main` function until the promise on its RHS is resolved.

1. You create the first promise
2. You create the second promise
3. You call `main`
4. `main` is suspended until `promise1` resolves
5. Two seconds later `promise2` resolves
6. Two seconds after that `promise1` resolves
7. `main` wakes up
8. `main` is suspended until `promise2` resolves which **already** happened at step 5 so it wakes up again immediately

If you want to avoid calling the function you pass to the second `setTimeout` until the the first promise has resolved, then put it in a function can call it from `main` **at the time you want to call it**.

```js
const func1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("promise1");
    resolve("promise1");
  }, 4000);
});

const func2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("promise2");
    resolve("promise2");
  }, 2000);
});

async function main() {
  const result1 = await func1();
  const result2 = await func2();
  console.log("end");
}

main();
```